# Can I use Character Encoding for Regular Expressions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, regex

Can I use Character Encoding for Regular Expressions...?

e.g.

```
this.html().replace(/&lt;\/?[^&gt;]+>/gi, '')
```

Instead of:

```
this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "use" ..

Inside a regex literal, `&lt;` will never translated or considered the same as `<`. That doesn't mean you can't use it in your expression, it just means you'll be matching `&lt;` rather than `<`

```
var x = "<html>";

x.match('<[^>]+>'); // => <html>
x.match('&lt;[^>]+>'); // => null
```